# can you explain me use of Had I

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know the structure of "Hardly **had I** slept when the telephone rang" or can we use hardly I had slept when the telephone rang.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is making use of [Inversion](https://literarydevices.net/inversion/). The same sentence without Inversion would be:

> I had hardly slept when the telephone rang.

which means the same thing as

> Hardly had I slept when the telephone rang.